# How many people are helping to moderate this site?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation, data-explorer

For a SE site to be successful, we need people to help moderate it. The more help, the better.

So, I'm wondering, could we have some information about how many *different* people help moderate this site?

Information like:

- How many different people voted to close a question in the last 1 months, 3 months and 6 months?
- How many different people voted to reopen a question in the last 1 months, 3 months and 6 months?
- How many different people voted to delete an answer in the last 1 months, 3 months and 6 months?

I would also be interested in knowing how many different people raised a (valid) flag in the last 1 months, 3 months and 6 months, but those are not public information, so it might not be possible to know that.

Comment: So there is a `Votes` table that contains close/reopen/delete vote records. However, the `UserId`'s are omitted from these records (there's like some MSE posts on this). The only votes that `UserId` is recorded for in SEDE are Favorite and Bounty Start. As such, I'm not sure if there's an easy way to get the data you're looking for.

Comment: @scohe001 Arf :/ So, I guess the solution is "do it by hand or ask a SE employe" then

Comment: I have a hacky solution, but it'll only catch cases where the question was actually closed or reopened (which kind of makes sense since all other votes will be aged away and deleted from the db eventually anyways I guess?). I'll post the query in a minute here.

Answer (score 4):

[Click here to see the query I wrote to fetch those numbers](https://data.stackexchange.com/interpersonal/query/1197677/number-of-unique-users-closing-questions?sd=2020-01-01&ed=2020-02-01) (Action type must be one of {10 - Close, 11 - Reopen, 12 - Delete, 13 - Undelete}).

Like I mentioned in a comment, we have a `Votes` table that has all of the close/reopen/delete votes (in addition to the rest). However, `UserId`'s aren't recorded for those in an attempt to keep some privacy.

So to find this data, we need to be a little...less conventional. There's a `PostHistory` table that contains actions taken on a post (delete/undelete/close/reopen), and in *that*, there's a JSON column that contains a list of users who took action on the post (if applicable).

All this to say, pulling the data from `PostHistory` is possible, but this will only give us users who contributed a vote to a question that was eventually closed/reopened/deleted/undeleted, not any that made votes that then aged away. In addition, only data for non-deleted questions is available here, so you'll only be seeing delete/undelete votes for questions that were eventually undeleted.

Let me know if you have any questions about it or if you need more data!

```
-- at: Action Type "10 - Close, 11 - Reopen, 12 - Delete, 13 - Undelete"
-- sd: Start date "yyyy-mm-dd format"
-- ed: End date "yyyy-mm-dd format"

DECLARE @atype INT = ##at:int##
DECLARE @sdate NVARCHAR(10) = ##sd:string##
DECLARE @edate NVARCHAR(10) = ##ed:string##
DECLARE @startdate DATE = CAST(@sdate as date)
DECLARE @enddate DATE = CAST(@edate as date)

SELECT
  ph.PostId, ph.CreationDate, voter_id INTO #voter_ids
FROM PostHistory ph
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (ph.Text)
  WITH (
    voters NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.Voters' AS JSON
  )
  OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(voters)
  WITH (voter_id NVARCHAR(20) '$.Id')
WHERE ph.PostHistoryTypeId = @atype -- Close 
  AND ph.CreationDate >= @startdate AND ph.CreationDate < @enddate

SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT voter_id) [Num Voters] 
FROM
  #voter_ids
WHERE
  voter_id != -1 -- Don't count the deleted user
```

Just for completeness sake, [here's a modified version of the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/interpersonal/query/1197709?at=10&sd=2020-01-01&ed=2020-02-01) that lists who voted and how many times they voted (ordered by most votes).

Comment: That's awesome! Thank scohe!

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think that the PostHistory table contain data only about posts which are not deleted. (I believe the only data about deleted posts are the ones in the PostsWithDeleted table.) So this means that if we check [deleted votes](https://data.stackexchange.com/interpersonal/query/1197709?at=10&sd=2020-01-01&ed=2020-02-01&at=12), we only see questions which were later undeleted. Is that correct or did I miss something?

Comment: Huh, you know that actually sounds right @Martin. I was wondering why those numbers looked so small. I'll add a note to the post. Thanks for pointing that out!!